# more efficient way of using .on() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently building an `app` that has makes use of the `.on()` in `jQuery`.

What I've noticed is, i am making alot of use of the `.on()` method. so much so, that it feels like my code is starting to become very messy.

```
$(document).on('click','.close-comments',function(){
shrinkComments();
});
// end function

$(document).on('click','.reload',function(){
// perform reload
});
// end function

$(document).on('click','.write-comment',function(){
});
// end function

$(document).on('click','#load-more',function(){
});
// end function
```

What I'm wondering is... is there a more efficient way of using the `.on()` method to handle a variety of different clicks on things that may be happening throughout the page?

Alot of the content is loaded via `ajax`, so the content will vary, but im just looking for a more elegant way of using this method so my code is much more leaner and more efficient

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"? Normally when people use that term, they mean how quickly the code runs, but it sort of sounds like you might mean "less typing" or something along those lines here.

Comment: yeah thats what I mean, More efficient in regards to not writing out .***.on() so many times down the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickHandlers = {
  '.close-comments' : function() {
    shrinkComments();
  },
  '.reload': function() {
    // perform reload
  },
  '.write-comment': function() {
  },
  '#load-more': function() {
  }
};
for (var selector in clickHandlers) {
  $(document).on('click', selector, clickHandlers[selector]);
}
```

If you want to handle events other than `click`, you could add another layer to your `handler` object and another layer in the for loop.